# PHP merge docx all images is replaced

Tags: php, merge, docx

I have a problem:

I've tried this url [enter link description here](https://github.com/JohannCOSTE/phpMergeDocx)

To merge docx in PHP, It's worked, but, I've found one problem that all images of docx files will be replaced by first file image?

Is there any solution? Thank you so much

Here is code:

```
function merge2Docx($document1, $document2, $outputfile){
if (file_exists($document1) && file_exists($document2)) {
    $zip = new clsTbsZip();

    // Open the first document
    $zip->Open($document1);
    $content1 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
    $zip->Close();

    // Extract the content of the first document
    $p = strpos($content1, '<w:body');
    if ($p === false){
        // Tag <w:body> not found in document 1
        return null;
    }
    $p = strpos($content1, '>', $p);
    $content1 = substr($content1, $p + 1);
    $p = strpos($content1, '</w:body>');
    if ($p === false){
        // Tag </w:body> not found in document 1
        return null;
    }
    $content1 = '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page" /><w:lastRenderedPageBreak/></w:r></w:p>'.substr($content1, 0, $p);


    // Insert into the second document
    $zip->Open($document2);
    $content2 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
    $p = strpos($content2, '</w:body>');
    if ($p === false){
        // Tag </w:body> not found in document 2
        return null;
    }

    $content2 = substr($content2, 0, $p) . $content1 . substr($content2, $p);
    $zip->FileReplace('word/document.xml', $content2, TBSZIP_STRING);

    // Save the merge into a third file
    $zip->Flush(TBSZIP_FILE, $outputfile);
    if(file_exists($outputfile)) return $outputfile;
    else return null;
} else {
    // $document1 or $document2 doesn't exist
    return null;
}
```

}